# How to check for truthy values but without skipping the 0?

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe

I have a calculation script for a box and only one little problem: **I can't make both conditions A) and B) work at the same time.**

A) If I leave the **amount of kilometres** **empty**, I want the calculation script to deliver an **empty output** as well.

B) If I fill in a **0** as the **amount of kilometres**, I want the calculation script to deliver a **0** as an **output** as well.

*(boxes are formatted as a number and a 0 will always be displayed like "0,00")*

Can someone spot my mistake?

```
var v1 = +getField("amount_km").value;

if (v1 || v1 === 0) {
    event.value = 0.3 * (v1);
}
else {
    event.value = "";
}
```

Comment: why is there a + there? `+getField("amount_km").value;`

Comment: @TKoL that causes the string to be converted to a number.

Comment: `+''` results in `0`, which would fall into the first if, not the else, causing your A criteria to be false.  You should consider checking if the value exists or not, before doing any numeric comparisons/conversions

Comment: Yes, do the +getValue() inside of your A if statement.

Comment: @Taplar Perfect. Removing the + did the trick. I don't know anything about programming so with the information being given that this is superfluous it now works like a charm, thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 0):

This code handles the empty string case:

```
var v1 = getField("amount_km").value;
var numV1 = +v1;

if (v1 && (numV1  || numV1 === 0)) {
    event.value = 0.3 * (v1);
} else {
    event.value = "";
}
```

Comment: Given that the else should really only happen if the value is blank, the `if` conditional could be simplified to just `v1.trim()`

Comment: No, because they can put letters into the input. Perhaps he wants the else to run if they put in "abc", which it currently does

Comment: unfortunately, this script delivers the same outcome as the one used before :-( So if I type in a 0 as the amount of kilometres, the calculation of the box delivers an empty out

Comment: @TKoL that requirement is not included in the OP and would be scope creep.

Comment: @Taplar my solution is simple AND handles the additional case of nonnumeric strings. It's up to him

Comment: @user3821135 I'm running the code with a string of "0" and it works fine

Comment: I'm running it in an Adobe PDF - maybe that causes some differences? Anyway thanks for your help, but removing the + already simply solved it for my case :-)